# Explanation needed on this rather basic recurrence solution

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, recursive-algorithms

We are studying about recurrences in our analysis of algorithms class. As an example of the substitution method (with induction) we are given the following:
$$T(n) = \lbrace 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + n \quad\text{if}\quad n > 1\rbrace$$

First step in the substitution method: "Guess: $n \lg n + n$"
Second step: "Inductive step - Inductive hypothesis is that $T(k) = k \lg k + k$ for all $k < n$. We'll use this inductive hypothesis for $T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)$"

and following is the solution:

### \begin{align}
T(n) &= 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + n\\
     &= 2\left(\frac{n}{2} \log \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{2}\right) + n\\
     &= n \lg \frac{n}{2} + n + n\\
     &= n\left(\lg n - \lg 2\right) + n + n\\
     &= n \lg n - n + n + n\\
     &= n \lg n + n\\
\end{align}

I have got so many questions and it frightens me to death that I don't grasp this concept :/

1. Where is the inductive step here like we have in induction when working with sums e.g. prove for $n + 1$
2. How did the author get from this:
   $$\dots = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + n$$ 
   to this 
   $$\dots = 2\left(\frac{n}{2} \log \frac{n}{2} + \frac{n}{2}\right) + n$$
3. I absolutely don't get the last lines of the solution :
   \begin{align}
   & = n \lg \frac{n}{2} + n + n\\
   & = n\left(\lg n - \lg 2\right) + n + n\\
   & = n \lg n - n + n + n\\
   \end{align}

Have I forgotten basic properties of logarithms? Truth be told I have been a software developer for the past 2 years and am getting ready for my masters which start in 3 weeks..

Thanks for your patience and your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the recurrence relation for [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). By induction of successive powers of 2, your recurrence relation reduces to $\displaystyle T(n) = 2^k T \left ( \frac{n}{2^k} \right ) + c n k$.

Assuming that $n = 2^k$ and that $T(1) = 1$, then $\displaystyle T(n) = n + c n \log_2(n)$. Thus the algorithm is on the order $\mathcal{O}(n \log_{2}n)$.

Comment: You lost me there.. how did you and the authors get that log2 in the solution? I am especially puzzled by the authors solution to the problem. Could you mind explaning it line by line if possible? Thanks

Comment: @Peter, Given $n = 2^k$, $\log(n) = k \log(2) \implies k = \log(n) / log(2) = \log_{2}(n)$. Thus when you take the recurrence relation in my answer, you get $n + cn \log_{2}(n)$ by substituting $2^k$ with $n$ and $k$ with $\log_2(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

This recurrence has the nice property that we can compute explicit values for $T(n)$ the same way as was done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270591/recurrence-relation-by-substitution), for example. Let $$n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^k$$ be the binary digit representation of $n.$ Assuming that $T(0)=0$, it is not difficult to see that $$ T(n) = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 2^j \sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^{k-j} = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} \sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} d_k 2^k$$
For an upper bound, consider values of $n$ consisting entirely of one digits, which gives
$$T(n) \le \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} \sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 2^k = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}
\left( 2^{1+ \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} - 2^j \right) =
(1+ \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor) 2^{1+ \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}
- 2^{1+ \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} + 1 =
\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor 2^{1+ \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} + 1.$$
For a lower bound, consider a one digit followed by zeros, which gives
$$T(n) \ge \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor} =
(1+ \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor) 2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}.$$
Taking these two bounds together, we have shown that
$$ T(n) \in \Theta\left(\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor  2^{\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}\right).$$
But we have $$ \log_2 n -1 < \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor \le \log_2 n$$ so that this is
$$ T(n) \in \Theta\left(\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor n\right) =
\Theta\left(n \log_2 n\right).$$
The lower bound shows that the next term asymptotically is $n.$