# Solving a recurrence relation $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{4}) + c$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a recurrence relation that I would like to solve. $T(n)$ belongs to $\Theta(f(n))$.

$T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{4}) + c$, where $c$ is a constant. The base case, $T(1)$ is a constant as well.

My approach was to let $n = 4^k$, but I guess I got confused with the expansion. Can someone show me the first couple of expansions and the closed form? Would appreciate it as it would help me learn this.

EDIT: My work so far ...
$$\begin{align}
T(4^k) &= 2&T(4^k) & &+ c \\
       &= 2&(2T(4^{k-1}) &+ c) &+c \\
       &= 2&(2T(2T(4^{k-2}) + c) &+ c) &+c
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_k = T(4^k)$. Then $x_{k+1} = 2 x_k +c$. The solution is $x_k = 2^k x_o + c (2^k-1)$. Hence $T(4^k) = 2^kT(1)+c(2^k-1)$.

Letting $n = 4^k$ gives $2^k = \sqrt{n}$, so we have $T(n) = \sqrt{n}T(1) + c(\sqrt{n}-1)$ (for $n \in \{ 4^k \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$).

Comment: thank you for your response. Did you get your answer by plugging it into the recurrence relation? Did it look like something like this? 
let n=^k, T(4^k)= 2T(4^k) + c ... 
2[2T[4^(k-1)] + c] +c ... 2[2T[2T[4^(k-2)] + c] + c] +c

Comment: No. I transformed it into the linear system $x_{k+1} = 2 x_k +c$ which has a standard solution. $x_{k+1} = T(4^{k+1}) = 2T(4^k) +c = 2 x_k +c$.

Comment: Do you mind looking at my steps in top and tell me if I am correctly recursing on it? I am not sure if I should be dividing c by 4.

Comment: I want to see if I can get what you got

Comment: Just apply the formula. $T(4^k) = 2 T(4^{k-1})+c = 2 (2 T(4^{k-2})+c)+c = 2^2 T(4^{k-2}) + c(2^1+2^0)$.

Comment: Would the runtime of this be O(√n) or O(log√n)?

Comment: Assuming $T(n)$ is the runtime, it would be $O(\sqrt{n}) {}{}{}$. (If you can replace a job of size $n$ by two jobs of size $\frac{n}{4}$ plus constant, then you get nice sublinear behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple case of the Master theorem that can be solved exactly, the way that was done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313046/recurrence-relation-using-the-master-theorem-tn-4tn-2-n2-log-n). Let the representation in base 4 of $n$ be given by
$$ n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} d_k 4^k.$$

Now with $T(0)=0$, we have $$ T(n) = 
\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor} (2^j \times c) =
c \left(2^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor+1} -1\right).$$

Observe that $$ \log_4 n - 1 < \lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor \le \log_4 n$$
so that $$2^{\log_4 n} < 2^{\lfloor \log_4 n \rfloor+1} \le 2n^{\log_4 n}
\quad \text{and} \quad
c(\sqrt n-1) < T(n) \le c(2\sqrt n-1).$$
This allows us to conclude that $$T(n) \in \Theta(\sqrt n).$$