# Prove asymptotic bound by the substitution method

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

I need to prove that $T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n^2lgn = \mathcal{O}(n^2lg^2n)$ by using the substitution method. Unfortunately, I'm not able to identify the error in my train of thought.

For the problem at hand, I want to prove that $T(n) = \mathcal{O}(n^2lg^2n)$, equivalently that there exists a $n_0$ and $c > 0$ such that for every $n \geq n_0$ it holds that $T(n) \leq cn^2lg^2n$. So it follows that:
\begin{align}
T(n) &= 4T(n/2) + n^2lgn \\
&\leq 4c\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2lg^2\left( \frac{n}{2} \right) + n^2lgn \\
&= cn^2lg^2n - cn^2 + n^2lgn \\
&\leq cn^2lg^2n 
\end{align}

The last inequation holds when
$$
- cn^2 + n^2lgn \leq 0
$$
or, equivalently
$$
c \geq lgn
$$

which cannot be true since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} lgn = \infty$.

I would be very thankful to anyone who can point to where my error comes from, or at least point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: This [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601295/) may prove helpful reading. The logarithm term in the recurrence can be simplified (basic exercise) but the asymptotics are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in algebra.

Assuming $lg\ 2 = 1$,

\begin{align}
T(n) &= 4T(n/2) + n^2lgn \\
&\leq 4c\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2lg^2\left( \frac{n}{2} \right) + n^2lgn \\
&= cn^2(lg\ n-lg\ 2)^2 + n^2lgn \\
&= cn^2(lg\ n-1)^2 + n^2lgn \\
&= cn^2(lg^2\ n-2lg\ n+1) + n^2lgn \\
&= cn^2lg^2n-2cn^2lg\ n+cn^2 + n^2lgn \\
&= cn^2lg^2n-n^2lg\ n(2c-1)+cn^2  \\ 
\end{align}

To make this
less than
$ cn^2lg^2n$,
we must have
$2c-1
< 0
$
or
$c < \frac12$
(assuming I did not make my own mistake).

Comment: Oh my, I feel ashamed... Thank you a lot, @martycohen!